# Pointer empty in 64-bit mode

Tags: c#, api, dll

I am trying to connect to "Train Simulator 2021" via an existing C++ DLL I access in my C# application. The content of the DLL is unknown to me, except function names I am aware of. I do the following to access these functions:

```
namespace RailSimulatorLibrary
{
    public class RailSimulatorInterface
    {
        [DllImport("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\RailWorks\\plugins\\RailDriver.dll", EntryPoint = "GetLocoName", ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetLocoName();
    }
}
```

Then calling this function in my Windows Form App:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentLocoName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(RailSimulatorInterface.GetLocoName());
    Console.WriteLine(currentLocoName);
}
```

When I run the 32bit version of Train Sim, I get a correct return value. When running it in 64 Bit though, the pointer is zero. I was wondering if IntPtr is a 32bit return type and I need to return differently for 64bit?

I used the RailDriver64.dll for the 64-bit test, but in that case I get an empty Pointer, even though trainsim has been started as 64-bit.

Comment: you can't use the same native dll in a 32-bit and 640bit application

Comment: Check if there's ```"RailDriver64.dll"``` file.

Comment: Open up the DLL in Dependency Viewer

Comment: Ah sorry. I have to edit that post. I have used the RailDriver64.dll actually. I tested it and the pointer was empty. Setting it to 32bit and using Raildriver.dll only, showed the correct value (rest of the code being the same)

Answer (score -3):

You need to use 64bit dll in a 64bit application.
I can see you're using 32 bit dll from its path.